# (Tauri) js import not working: "Failed to resolve module specifier"

Tags: javascript, desktop-application, tauri

I'm encountering a problem with Tauri plugins (I'm using Tauri 1.2.2).
I've created a basic app with

```
npx create-tauri-app
```

with npm as its package manager.

I've left everything the way it was installed, except for the fact that I'm trying to use the Plugin-Log plugin for Tauri.
(https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri-plugin-log)

To install it, I've added

```ini
tauri-plugin-log = { git = "https://github.com/tauri-apps/plugins-workspace", branch = "dev" }
```

in `src-tauri/Cargo.toml`, then ran

```
npm add https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri-plugin-log
```

then I updated my `main()` function in `src-tauri/src/main.rs`:

```rust
use tauri_plugin_log::{LogTarget};
fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_log::Builder::default().targets([
            LogTarget::LogDir,
            LogTarget::Stdout,
            LogTarget::Webview,
        ]).build())
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![greet])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

However, when I attempt to import anything (the line of code below was written inside `main.js`):

```js
import { trace, info, error, attachConsole } from "tauri-plugin-log-api";
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tauri-plugin-log-api". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Even imports taken straight from the documentation, such as this one, fail:

```js
import { ask } from '@tauri-apps/api/dialog';
const yes = await ask('Are you sure?', 'Tauri');
```

and result in the same `TypeError`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@tauri-apps/api/dialog". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

despite the fact that I've added the following to `tauri.conf.json`

```json
{
  "tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "dialog": {
        "all": true,
        "open": true,
        "save": true
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The only workaround for the above problem I have found is this:

```json
const { ask } = window.__TAURI__.dialog;
const yes = await ask('Are you sure?', 'Tauri');
```

which ends up working.

Unfortunately, I remain at a loss trying to use the Plugin-Log described earlier in this post.
I tried using a relative path i.e.

```js
import { trace, info, error, attachConsole } from "../node_modules/tauri-plugin-log-api/dist-js/index.min.js";
```

but then a new error occurs:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I even tried reproducing the issue in a fresh VM after installing everything and I end up with the same errors.

Could there be something that I'm missing? Please bear with me as I am a literal Tauri noob.
Thank you in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 2):

Docs aren't updated but you're just missing:

```
yarn add -D @tauri-apps/api
```

Comment: This one works in my case. For anyone that has the same problem, and chatGPT still cannot help you. Make sure you have `@tauri-apps/api` in the dependency of your package.json.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same errors when using 'import' declarations from '@tauri-apps/api' using Tauri installed as vanilla JS/CSS/HTML.

The only fix I found was copying my HTML/JS/CSS code into a [vanilla-ts] version of Tauri where it worked as expected.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Have you been able to resolve the issue over the last week?  Currently dealing with this same issue, and im not sure if its a bug or im just very new

Comment: Asides from using typescript instead of javascript, I haven't. I can import functions from plugins and functions from (@tauri-apps) api, fs, path etc. 
I'm not sure why but the typescipt version comes with vite and all the @tauri-apps pre-installed while the javascript doesn't for some insight.

Comment: Worth noting, I am extremely new with web development so there may be an obvious solution somewhere.

Comment: I had to talk with the devs on discord.  The documents could use some work, lets just say that.  The vanilla versions use the withglobaltauri=true configuration in conf.json file, which is why I think it works.  So their recommended method of setting up the app is not the version which is easiest to get working.  They should have updated docs soon.  Get on the tauri discord and @WhisperingShiba, I maybe I can walk you through what I know now

Comment: That's awesome thanks! Will do after I've finished work

Answer (score 1):

I see.you are writing it in this way

```
import { isPermissionGranted } from '@tauri-apps/api/notification'
```

Try writing it this way.it fixed for me

```
const { isPermissionGranted } = window.__TAURI__.notification;
```

replace api/notification with .notification.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as DaftRaven using the vanilla js version of Tauri and i solved it from changing import syntax to access Tauri using the window.

from

```
import { WebviewWindow } from '@tauri-apps/api/window';
```

to

```
const { WebviewWindow } = window.__TAURI__.window;
```